# template deduction of member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm trying to understand template argument deduction with regular functions, pointer to regular functions, member functions and pointer to member functions. Can someone explain why the last line yields a compile error while there is no issue with standalone?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
 
struct A {
    int fun(float, char) const&;
};
 
void standalone(int, char) {}

template <typename T>
void what(T &&) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}
 
int main() 
{
    what(standalone); // void what(T&&) [with T = void (&)(int, char)]
    what(decltype(&standalone){}); // void what(T&&) [with T = void (*)(int, char)]
    what(decltype(&A::fun){}); // void what(T&&) [with T = int (A::*)(float, char) const &]
    what(A::fun); // main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
                  // main.cpp:30:13: error: invalid use of non-static member function 'int A::fun(float, char) const &'
      |           // what(A::fun);
      |             ^~~
}
```

Comment: Non-member functions naturally decay to pointers to themselves. That is, `what(standalone)` is the same as `what(&standalone)`. This decay does not happen for member functions. And functions, member or non-member, can't be passed as themselves. Only pointers to functions can be passed as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that we cannot pass a reference to a member because from [Pointers to members](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf):

> The type “pointer to member” is distinct from the type “pointer”, that is,
> a pointer to member is declared only by the pointer to member declarator syntax, and never by the pointer
> declarator syntax. **There is no “reference-to-member” type in C++**.

This means that we must **explicitly** use the *address of operator* in the call expression to pass a pointer to member instead(since reference to member is not allowed), as shown below:

```
//-------v---------> must explicitly use address of operator
    what(&A::fun);
```

##### Side note

Although irrelevant in your case, note that unlike ordinary function pointers, there is **no automatic conversion** between a member function and a pointer to that member. That is, in case of member functions and in contexts where a pointer is expected(allowed) the expressions `A::fun` and `&A::fun` are **not equivalent**.

Comment: `standalone` and `&standalone` are not equivalent in OP's example either.

Comment: Yes, but in general(i.e., in many contexts excluding OP's) for a free function named `f` the expression `f` and `&f` are equivalent.

Comment: @user17732522 in C++ a function formally is a type (see ISO standard).  While decay to pointer indeed is possible, && promotes perfect forwarding here. THat allows to differentiate a raw function pointer from a function.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yes, the intention of my first comment was to hint at, that in the question implicit function-to-pointer decay is irrelevant for the reason you stated.

Comment: @user17732522 I have added some relevant explanation which explains exactly the reason for the OP's code's error. Check out the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a standalone function, a pointer to function can be converted contextually to function reference, e.g. in order to be called. A function can be converted to a pointer to itself. In result those two lines are both legal and equal.

```
what(standalone); 
what(*********************************************standalone); // stars!
```

For every star its argument is a reference and is contextually converted to a pointer, the result would be a reference, and so on. In C++ a function (reference) is a type.

The expression `&standalone` is explicitly a pointer, so `what(&standalone);` would be using a pointer.

Now a pointer to member is a type distinct from a usual pointer and has no analog in form of reference. The only legal way to obtain a pointer to member function or member variable is to combine unary `operator&` with its nested name.

Answer (score 0):

Non-static member functions are very different from free functions. They can only be used in a very limited number of ways.

The only possible uses for a non-static member function are in a member access expression to call the function or as an operand to `&` to form a pointer-to-member.

`A::fun` by itself isn't even syntactically correct in an expression if it is not preceded by `&` or a member access operator. `decltype(A::fun)` is also ill-formed.